# Show that every Cauchy sequence can have at most one limit point.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Show that every Cauchy sequence can have at most one limit point.

**My solution**

If a Cauchy sequence $x_{n}$ admits a limit point $L$, then there is a subsequence of $x_{n}$ which converges to $L$. Therefore $x_{n}$ converges to $L$. Since the limit of a sequence is unique in a metric space, the result holds.

Can someone check if is it right? An answer based on $\varepsilon-\delta$ definitions would be nice.

**Edit 1**

My answer is based on the following result:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in it. Then, if $x_{n}$ admits a subsequence which converges to $x_{0}$, then the Cauchy sequence is also convergent and $x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0}$.

**Edit 2**

Since my question has caused some confusion, I am going to explicit what I was looking for.

The proposition "if $L$ is a limit point of the sequence $x_{n}$, then there is a subsequence of $x_{n}$ which converges to $L$" has been proved earlier as well as the other two results involved in the solution.

Maybe I should have asked for an alternative solution involving $\varepsilon-\delta$, but as it has been pointed out it does not make sense since they are already involved in the assumptions used to solve the problem.

Anyway, thank you guys for the feedback.

Comment: How do you know that there is not another subsequence which converges to a different limit point, say $M$?

Comment: Please clarify: where does your Cauchy sequence come from? A metric space? Real numbers?

Comment: @sranthrop It comes from a generic metric space. I will edit my question in order to make it clearer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have edited my post. Does it answer your question?

Comment: "If a Cauchy sequence xn admits a limit point L, then there is a subsequence of xn which converges to L."  Why?  What result assures that if a cauchy sequence has a limit point then there exists a subsequence convergent to it. ... and you cite a result.  What if I said I don't get or believe that result?  Could you prove the result is asked? ... You shouldn't just remember results in hopes of pulling the right one at the right time.  You should instead be *more* comfortable going back to definitions and proving results directly.

Comment: @fleablood When I look at what is going on here, what comes to mind is 'putting the cart before the horse'. #confused

Comment: Oh,  I see what CopyPasteIt means by "cart before horse".  And I agree.  That a cauchy sequence has a single limit point is a much more basic result, then the result about subsequences that it seems you should prove this first.  Also, I really don't know how the subsequence result was proven and I *very* strongly suspect that there only being a single limit point was assumed.  I honest can't imagine this argument not being circular.

Comment: @fleablood I have tried to prove it at

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664329/prove-that-cauchy-sequences-are-convergent-when-they-admit-a-convergent-subseque

If you could verify whether this is valid or not, I would appreciate.

Comment: I didn't go over your work with a fine tooth comb but it seems to me that as part of the proof you *proved* this result in the middle of it.  After all $\{x_n\}$ is a subsequence of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any metric space is $T_2$, or Hausdorff.  This ensures that sequences have unique limits.  A Cauchy sequence is in particular a sequence.

Suppose$x_n\to x$ and $x_n\to y$.  Let $U_x,U_y$ be separating neighborhoods for $x$ and $y$.  Then $U_x$ contains $x_n$ for all $n\gt N$, for some $N$.  But since $U_x$ and $U_y$ are disjoint, it follows that $U_y$ contains only finitely many $x_n$.  So $x_n\not\to y$.

The converse is also true.  For instance, the cofinite topology on $\Bbb Z$ is a space that is not $T_2$ and limit points aren't unique.  For $x_n=n$ converges to every $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume there are two subsequence $ x_{\phi(n)} $ and $ w_{\psi(n)} $ such that

$$x_{\phi(n)}\to L_1$$
and
$$x_{\psi(n)}\to L_2$$

Given $ \epsilon>0$,

we know that
$$\phi(n)\ge n ; \psi(n)\ge n$$

then there exists $N_1, N_2,N_3 \ge 0$ such that
$$n\ge \max(N_1,N_2,N_3) \implies$$

$$|L_1-L_2|=|L_1-x_{\phi(n)} +x_{\phi(n)}-x_{\psi(n)}+x_{\psi(n)}-L_2|\le \frac \epsilon 3+\frac \epsilon 3 +\frac \epsilon 3$$

We conclude that $$L_1=L_2$$

Answer (score 2):

This is standard excercise.

The gyst is: If $\{x_n\}$ has two limit points $L_1$ and $L_2$ then we can take milestones $N_1, N_2$ large enough so that $x_m; m > N_1 $are all arbitrarily close to $L_1$ and $x_n; n > N_2$ are all arbitrarily close to $L_2$ but $L_1$ and $L_2$ are a specific distance apart so the $x_m$ arbitrarily close to $L_1$ are significantly far from the $x_n$ which are arbitrarily close to $L_1$ so the $x_k$ aren't arbitrarily close to each other which contradicts the sequence be Cauchy.

Can you formalize this?  Hint:

Triangle inequality says that if $|x_m - L_1| < D_1$ and $|x_n - L_2| < D_2$ then $|L_1 - L_2| = |(L_1 - x_m) + (x_m -x_n) + (x_n - L_2)| \le |x_m-L_1| + |x_m-x_n| +|x_n-L_2| < D_2 + D_1 + |x_m- x_n|$.

But what if $|L_1 - L_2| > D_2 + D_1$.  That would be a contradiction, wouldn't it?

Can you formalize that?

Hint:  Let $|L_1 - L_2| = K > 0$ and let $\epsilon < \frac K3$.

1) $\{x_n\}$ is cauchy so .... what?

> There is an $N_1$ so that if $m,n> N_1$ then $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$.

2) $L_1$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}$ so .... what?

> There is an $N_2$ so that if $m>N_2$ then $|L_1 - x_m| < \epsilon$

3) $L_2$ is a limit point of $\{x_m\}$ so ... what?

> There is an $N_3$ so that if $n > N_3$ then $|x_n - L_2| < \epsilon$.

So can we formalize:  Heres a hint:

> Let $N = \max(N_1, N_2, N_3)$.

So what happens if $n,m > N$.

> Then $|L_1 -x_m| < \epsilon;  |x_m - x_n| < \epsilon; |x_n - L_1| < \epsilon$ so $|L_1 - L_2|\le |L_1 -x_m|+|x_m - x_n|+|x_n - L_1| < 3\epsilon < K = |L_1 -L_2|$.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, @fleablood. It was really helpful. I have also edited my question in order to avoid (more) confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I stated in a comment below the OP's question that I am a bit confused here. Although the OP also asked for an $\varepsilon \mid \delta$ argument (uh, an $\varepsilon \mid N$), a good idea at this point is to just give a hint for the problem at hand.

PROBLEM; Show that every C̶a̶u̶c̶h̶y̶  $\,$sequence can have at most one limit point.

HINT: Let $a, b$ be any two distinct points in a metric space $X$ and let $l = d(a,b)$. Then

$\quad \{x \in X \mid d(a,x) \lt \frac{l}{2}l \} \; \bigcap \; \{x \in X \mid d(b,x) \lt \frac{l}{2}l \} = \emptyset $

Comment: That's very nicely putt.  I don't tend to  think of $\delta,\epsilon, N$ proofs in terms of set notation because it wasn't what I was taught but it sure is more intuitive to me an I really should.  The problem with traditional $\delta, \epsilon N$ proofs is that tend to bog down in technical detaills that one can lose the intuitive "obviousness" of what is going on.... also you are right, that the sequence is Cauchy is not nesc.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score -1):

A Cauchy sequence is a convergent sequence so it has exactly 1 limit point, not at most 1.

Edit: If the sequence comes from real numbers.

Comment: This is not true in incomplete spaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out; I edited my answer.

Comment: That's precisely what is being asked to be proven.